# EF Core 3.1 database first removed relation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

Have a table (tblCalculation) that had two related tables (tblAddon and tblVehicle) with foreign keys AddonId and VehicleId. Had scaffolded the context and models in my c# core 3.1 application. I then had to change the relationships of that table and remove the relation to tblVehicle table, so I removed the relationship in SSMS and deleted the foreign key VehicleId. Did the same in my code and removed the property VehicleId on the Calculation model and removed the HasOne(..).WithMany(...) definition from the OnModelCreating setup.

But when trying to load the table (which has been empty through this process) I get Invalid column name 'VehicleId'. Loading the (still empty" table in SSMS works fine but this code generates the error:

```
var calculations = await _context.Calculation.ToListAsync();
```

Is there some reference in ef I'm missing or what is the issue?

EDIT:
Ran a Scaffold-DbContext again and can't find any reference to a VehicleId

```
public partial class Calculation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AddonId { get; set; }
    public byte Period { get; set; }
    public short Mileage { get; set; }
    public decimal? ResidualValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? MonthlyCost { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Addon Addon { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Calculation>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Created)
                .HasColumnType("datetime")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.Property(e => e.MonthlyCost).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.ResidualValue).HasColumnType("money");

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.UpdatedBy).HasMaxLength(50);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Addon)
                .WithMany(p => p.Calculation)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AddonId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_tblCalculation_tblAddon");
        });
```

Replacing the current context's models with the temporary ones creates the same issue but running the identical models in the temporary context works. So something in the context keeps a reference to VehicleId but can't find it. So will generate a completely separate context (since there are other tables in the original context) and run from that.

Comment: Easiest solve? Scaffold it again to another folder and use a diff tool (recommend BeyondCompare) to see the differences. There will be a VehicleId lingering somewhere that was forgotten, I think.. Or you can just scaffold it again and use the new scaff. If you customize the ents, do it in partial classes so that re-scaffing doesn't overwrite all your changes. EF Core Power Tools is a big help if you get into re-scaffing on a regular basis (I find repeated re-scaff easier for beta/unreleased iterations, than migrations.. Especially when there are changes like renaming columns and tables)

Comment: @CaiusJard if you answer with this I can accept the answer. I you see in my edits running identical models in the same context generates the error but running in a separate context seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to scaffold the database again. This should give you a working context that you can use as a complete replacement for the one you have. If you have customized the models in your existing context you'll need to copy the changes over. This can be made easier with a tool like BeyondCompare; scaffold your db to a new, different folder to the one that the existing context is in, then (and these are BeyondCompare specific instructions) in windows explorer right click the new folder and choose "select left folder for compare", then go to the folder the existing context is in and right click, choose "compare to otherfolder". A side by side window pair appear, press Ctrl A and pick Compare Contents from one of the menus (I forget which, maybe Session or Action). BC will compare all the files and show any with DM significant differences in red. Double click a red file to see a side by side diff and use the arrows to copy from old to new, or use it to find any lingering files in your old context where VehicleId is still mentioned (it could be in a dependent related file, other than the ones you're focused on in the question)

Once you have made one context or the other be your main one, delete the other context.